# Request browser to autofill differently on a subpath

Tags: html, autofill

Just a quick question about browser's autofill functions. I'm often bothered by the websites I build , that the browsers are trying to autofill the same credentials on the front-end as the back-end (`/admin`/).

I'm curious if someone has experience with this and if it can be done plainly with HTML (5/Meta?).

I wonder if I can tell the browser to register a subpath (http://www.domain.com/admin) separately in their local autofill list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standardized way to tell the browser *"consider this being is a different site"*, apart from actually *making* it a different site (e.g. placing admin UI under subdomain - `admin.domain.com`).

The only way for you is to disable the default browser autocompletion by using `autocomplete="off"` HTML attribute for `<input>` markup (you can disable it only in the admin subdirectory):

```
<input type="text" name="field" autocomplete="off" />
```

Acceptable solution is to use some type of **javascript autocompleter**. You can then store the history **locally in the client using cookies.** Using e.g. jquery autocompleter with local storage is very simple - look here:

[Autocomplete (jQuery UI) and localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10312711/684229)

Then you of course have full control on how the storage is done.

#### Note on security

If you really don't want users to autofill forms, you should know that while mostly the [browser will respect `autocomplete=off`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972455), users [fight against it for several reasons](http://randosity.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/stupid-security-measures-autocompleteoff/); they use plugins that will still autocomplete in this situation (e.g. [autocomplete on for FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/autocompleteon/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocomplete-on/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh)). User always wins in this case, the client may modify the HTML as he want. There are [security risks involved](http://yoast.com/autocomplete-security/) in reckless autocompletion, so you can try to persuade users that it's not good for them.

You can also find some useful comments here: [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/684229)